# List of Supported Locale per Android version

Tags: android, locale, translation

I was searching the net for an official list of supported locale(language) for each android SDK version from Google. Unfortunately, I can't find one and I was hoping someone can help me. The only list I can find that is somewhat official is the IANA Language Subtag Registry. Here is the link: http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

Comment: Please explain *exactly* what you mean by "list of supported locale(language) for each android SDK version from Google". The Android SDK does not support locales, at least in how I would use the terms. Android *devices* support locales, and the roster of locales varies by device (and sometimes by distribution channel for that device).

Comment: I thought the supported locales varies by Android OS/SDK version. So you mean just because two devices have the same OS version, it doesn't mean that both of them have the same set of supported locales, am I correct?

Comment: Locales vary by OEM, device, model, and everything else.  Not really by OS or SDK version.  OEMs release models of phones to regions, and install the locales those regions generally need.  Or that they want themselves-  Samsung installs Korean world wide for testing purposes, as their employees mostly are Korean.  So there really is no way to assume a locale is or isn't on a device by any kind of version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you mean just because two devices have the same OS version, it doesn't mean that both of them have the same set of supported locales, am I correct?

Correct. This is particularly true for low-end and older devices, as locales take up space. The Android Open Source Project (AOSP) ships with translations for its apps and for core OS messages. Device manufacturers then elect what locales they want to support for their device. In some cases, they remove locales, to save space. In some cases, they *add* locales, to cover some market that Android itself does not cover (though this is far less common nowadays, since the AOSP has a fairly robust set of translations).

So, all an OS version indicates is what the baseline set of locales is. What a given device running that OS version has may vary from that baseline.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped and provided me useful information.